# Keeping logic out of Microcontrollers/SBC

Tags: arduino, esp32

I have an ESP32 and one of the problems I'm having is keeping code up to date. OTA is a good solution; however, I keep running into problems with deep sleep and auto update.

I wanted to know if there's a solution where all logic is performed remotely, like say NodeRed and then the GPIO pins are controlled that way. So essentially, the ESP32 would send it's sensor data to NodeRed, NodeRed does the logic and then sends back which GPIO pins turn on and off.

Is there a solution such as this or does it have a name?

Comment: It seems that there would some logic ( or a control program ) in the ESP32 SBC. Without that you cant toggle GPIO pins on the board.  Another Microcontroller can control the ESP32 SBC remotely.  I imagine there would be some command and response interface between another MCU and ESP32 SBC  which has commands for the ESP32 to do something.  What type of interface is between another MCU and  ESP32?

Comment: it's called a `bridge` or `tcp to GPIO converter` or `USB to GPIO converter`

Comment: https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-arduino